# how to add array values in javascript using push

Tags: javascript

I have declared an array in JavaScript just view it.

> ```
> var a[];  
> a.push(number); 
> alert(a);
> ```

I am trying to send an integer values using push but total numbers that I am sending are not fixed. I want to get sum of all numbers which are passing from this array.

If there is any other solution which can be usable in web.

```
a.push(number)
```

How can I add all values passing from this loop?

Comment: `var a[];` is not valid JavaScript (should throw a SyntaxError), must be `var a = [];`.

Comment: Looks like a C programmer started javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please correct your JS code:

```
var 
    a = [],
    sum = 0;

a.push(1);
a.push(2, 5); 

for (var i in a) {

    sum += a[i];
}

alert('Total sum is: ' + sum);
```

It will be better if you read complete reference about JavaScript's arrays from [https://developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array)

Answer (score 0):

```
var total;
for (i = 0; i < a.length; i++) { 
    total += a[i] ;
}
alert(total);
```

`a[i]` will get the value of the given index which will be incremented with the previous value and the total sum will be stored in `total` variable

Answer (score 0):

With an array, you can use the [Reduce](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) function to sum all elements:

```js
var a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];

var sum = a.reduce(function(previousValue, currentValue, currentIndex, arr) {
  return previousValue + currentValue;
});

document.write('The total is: ' + sum);
```

Comment: It's longer than the normal for version